# How to get selected value from checkbox?

Tags: apex, jquery, apexinputcheckbox

I'm having a problem getting the selected value of an apex:inputCheckbox. I know how to do it with javascript and jquery but, the ids and the name  contains lots of stuff this is an example:

```
 <input id="j_id0:j_id2:formBusqueda:j_id101:1:bCheck" type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:formBusqueda:j_id101:1:bCheck" onclick="habilitarEditar();" data-id="checkId">
```

Comment: could you post the full code on how you did this with jQuery? I am having the same issue and the `is.(":checked")` is not responding. I am using an inputCheckbox which might be part of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking strictly to the example you provided and since you know how to use jQuery you will simply use the ends with selector:

```
$('[id$=bCheck]').is(':checked');
```

The stuff in front of the `bCheck` is dynamic ID parts the the visual force framework appends to ensure unique Ids across the DOM.

Comment: @user3336570 - Since you are new here if an answer is the solution to your questions it is generally expected that you mark it as accepted by clicking on the Checkmark under the vote count. This helps someone with a similar question find real answers

Comment: I had to wait ten minutes until I could give the mark